# Installing Angular 5 through which CLI version

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-cli, npm-install

I am using Ubuntu 18 and want to start the Angular 5 project and therefore I installed Node, npm, TypeScript and finally the 
latest stable Angular CLI by below command,

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

So, by default it is downloading the latest stable Angular CLI, which is now 6.1.3 and it's by default serve the Angular 6 version 
instead of Angular 5, which is my requirement.

There after I searched so many pages on same to get the right CLI version for the latest version 5.2.11 for Angular 5.

Also watched many post but many are from last year 2017, when the Angular 5 were newly published.

So my issue is to get Angular 5 latest version by installing which earlier version of Angular CLI?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OS: Ubuntu 18 (Linux)

Note: use `sudo` as prefix for installing. Windows user open the cmd as administrator.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

1. Installing NodeJS 8.11.3 LTS

   ```
   curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -

   sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

   node -v
   v8.11.3
   ```
2. **npm is installed with Node.js**

   npm is distributed with Node.js- which means that when you download Node.js, you automatically get npm installed on your computer.

   ```
   npm -v
   6.3.0
   ```
3. Get TypeScript

   ```
   sudo npm install -g typescript

   tsc -v
   Version 3.0.1
   ```
4. Use root to install angular/cli

   ```
   sudo -s
   root@ubuntu:~#
   ```
5. Use CLI version 1.6.6 for Angular 5.2.11

   ```
   root@ubuntu:~# npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.6
   // it will download files and take some minutes

   root@ubuntu:~# ng -v

       _                      _                 ____ _     ___
      / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
     / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
    / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
   /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                  |___/

   Angular CLI: 1.6.6
   Node: 8.11.3
   OS: linux x64
   Angular: 
   ...
   ```
6. Now, exit from root

   ```
   exit
   // reach where you want to create your new project
   ng new angular5App
   // it will download files and take some minutes
   ```
7. reach inside project directory

   ```
   cd angular5App
   // check project dependencies from package.json
   ```
8. compile, bundle and run the project

   ```
   ng serve -on
   ```
9. by default, your project will run on `http://localhost:4200/`

In Chrome 65 of above version, go to Inspect, Elements,

Inside `<body>` check `<app-root _nghost-c0="" ng-version="5.2.11">`

Comment: Just FYI ... you should not need step #3. Step #6 where you are creating the new application will install TypeScript for you. And please mark your reply as the answer to close this question. Thanks!

Comment: @DeborahK Yeah, you are right, but sometime people approaches through a different way, and simply perform the suggested one, and the result will - *it is not working...*, so I mention the complete process what I have followed.

Answer (score 0):

just do this

1. create new folder say "`angularprojects`"
2. go to "`angularprojects`"  folder using cmd
3. now run this cmd  : `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.6`
4. now create new project using `sudo ng new my-first-project` or paste exist project
5. now type `cd my-first-project`
6. now Run using `ng serve`